# Stop jQuery Animation for all Child Elements

Tags: jquery

Wish you all a Happy New Year folks!

I just wanted to ask if there was any way to stop jquery animation for ALL CHILD NODES of an element? I mean lets say if I have a below html structure in a document and I have applied different animations to all the div's inside the container - some also in queue=false etc.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="element-1"></div>
<div id="element-2"></div>
<div id="element-3"></div>
<div id="element-4"></div>
<div id="element-5"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to stop all animations for all elements inside the div instantly? Well okay, one would recall the below code immediately

```
$('#element-1, #element-2, #element-3, #element-4, #element-5').stop(true);
```

and it should stop all elements - instantly. And if we try

```
$('#element-1, #element-2, #element-3, #element-4, #element-5').stop(true, true);
```

The elements should jump to end result - **surely not working for me**. Kind of what is required but what if I have 300 elements animating at the same instant - I surely cannot apply the above method eh!

I was seeking something like

```
$('#container').stop(true,true);
```

Is some tweak possible?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: $('#container').children().stop(true,true); approach mentioned by Chimoo, should work

Comment: thanks for the comments, doesn't work. Seems like there is something in my code itself that is preventing it to... Shall find out soon. Thanks a ton folks!

Comment: children() will stop only direct children of #container. If there are any nested animated elements then find() should be used.

Optionally find can be used with :animated to select only elements that currently are animated - $('#container').find(':animated').stop(true, true);

Answer (score 4):

You can select all elements inside wrapper and stop then stop them. For your html this one should work:

```js
$('#container').find('*').stop(true, true);
```

Comment: I am not sure why but stop(true, true) is surely not working for me.