# If parent div is animated by jquery is it possible to prevent some child elements from animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if its possible to keep child elements from being animated. like in the following example: ( http://jsfiddle.net/JsfMF/6/ )

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function fade(){
     $('#fadethis').animate({opacity: 0}, 500).show('#nogoaway');
     };
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id ="fadethis">
        <p> I should go away </p>
        <p id="nogoaway">hi im not supposed to be animated</p>
    </div>
    <button id="fade" onClick="fade()">fade!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693112/stop-jquery-animation-for-all-child-elements

Comment: No, because cites is just stopping children that are animated; this has an animated parent.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Go back and read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not: HTML is structured around a tree of boxes; if you animate the parent, the children will get dragged along.

However, you could *simulate* this by having a parent that contains both *your* parent and the children.  The positioning and using the z axis will let you get the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as the opacity is applied to the element and all child elements. Though, you can achieve your desired behavior by moving `<p id="nogoaway"></p>` outside of `<div id="fadethis"></div>` and absolutely positioning it over `<div id="fadethis"></div>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id ="fadethis">
        <p> I should go away </p>
    </div>
    <p id="nogoaway">hi im not supposed to be animated</p>
</div>
```

***Side-Note:***

***jQuery UI** uses the same approach when popping modal dialogs*

Comment: @Xander...that's bad...i really need that <p> go away ;-P maybe someone else has an idea

Comment: @Jurudocs That's bad, how? You can't modify the `HTML`? This is not a "bad" option.

Comment: @Jurudocs This is the exact pattern that jQuery UI uses to pop modal `dialog`s...

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible because children are not "standalone". You can, however, animate only the children you want to animate: http://jsfiddle.net/JsfMF/9/.

```
function fade(){
    $('#fadethis').children(":not(#nogoaway)")
                  .animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
};​
```